# xcode 5 xctest testing async Login web service

Tags: ios7, xcode5, xctest

i have made an iOS app using XCode 5 and now i want to do unit testing for it, i have written test case for login service but the thing is that the request is forming properly but no response is coming and when we run the application normally we are receiving proper response, i have tested the same service with OCUnit and was facing no issues.is there any specific thing which we have to take care while testing web services with XCTest

Comment: If you don't provide any code, hardly will someone be able to help you.

Comment: loot into this... this can be helpfull https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/asynchronous-testing-with-xcode-6/

Answer (score 0):

With https://github.com/hfossli/AGAsyncTestHelper you can write

```
- (void)testAsyncBlockCallback
{
    __block BOOL jobDone = NO;

    [Manager doSomeOperationOnDone:^(id data) {
        jobDone = YES; 
    }];

    WAIT_WHILE(!jobDone, 2.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hfossli's macro is nice but doesn't add an input to the runloop hence making it [return immediately](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsrunloop_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRunLoop/runMode%3abeforeDate%3a) (provoking CPU hassle as far as I understand that code), here the code to fix it:

```
NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runLoop addPort:[NSMachPort port] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

wile(waitingForBlock){

    [runLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1f]];
}
```

plain simple complete example usage with an hypothetical AFNetworking call:

```
- (void)testSync{

    __block BOOL waitingForBlock = YES;

    [self.manager POST:k_WSERVICE_SYNC_ENDPOINT
            parameters:nil
               success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                XCTAssertTrue(responseObject != nil, @"Sync: Got empty response, should have received something");
                waitingForBlock = NO;

          } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                XCTFail(@"Sync: Failed to connet with error %@",error);
                waitingForBlock = NO;
          }];


    NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runLoop addPort:[NSMachPort port] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    while(waitingForBlock){

        [runLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1f]];
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the while loop version here, but if you're anything like me and hate from the bottom of your heart while loops, you know how to do it with a "for" one :) (In case you didn't: for(;waitingForBlock;){...} )